# If Statement to find if URL contains a certain word

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-analytics

Is there a way to write an if statement around the google analytics code so it knows I am in the DEV environment based on the URL?  This is on the index.html page.

Web.Config is out of the question for this.

Code right now:

```
  <script>alert(window.location.href + "test");</script> ---This is to see what URL I am using for my if statement 
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<number>"></script>
  <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', '<number>');
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the script tag to be dynamically appended to the DOM w/ javascript, and you can wrap the code in whatever condition you want. Not sure what your condition vs. action is, but here is an example of only executing the code if URL contains "test"

```
<script>
(function() {
    if (location.href.indexOf('test')>-1) {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<number>';
        s.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(s);

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', '<number>');
    }
})();

</script>
```